# Stop a process (script) from invoking oom killer

Tags: bash, oom-killer

I had a very unfortunate situation, where a bash script that contained a subtle error gone wild and took all available memory and then started killing other tasks (production apps!) to get even more.

How can I future-proof invocations of this and other scripts so when they reached memory limit they fall themselves and not kill other apps?

I'd prefer something I could incorporate into the text of the script.

Comment: You are running Linux, presumably? bash runs on several operating systems.

Comment: @JohnMahowald yes, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ulimit -m` will let you set a core (well, RSS) limit applicable to a process, and `ulimit -v` will let you do likewise for the VM footprint.

Comment: So, I ended up with a mix of @MadHatter and @JohnMahowald answers. First, `ulimit -m` is deprecated (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129592/285241), second, `vm.oom_kill_allocating_task=1` won't help, because both offending script and prod apps are allocating actively. Which led me to using `ulimit -v` and `echo 1000 > /proc/self/oom_score_adj`

Answer (score 2):

On Linux,  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt  documents a variety of tunables for the virtual memory system.

For example, `vm.oom_kill_allocating_task=1`

> If this is set to non-zero, the OOM killer simply kills the task that
>   triggered the out-of-memory condition.  This avoids the expensive
>   tasklist scan.

There is no guarantee your production apps won't be the ones triggering the OOM. But a runaway allocation is more likely to hit it.

There also is a score you can tweak to weight specific processes more or less likely to be murdered for their memory.  /proc/$PID/oom_adj.   Although, you probably want to set it in your init scripts.  [systemd.exec  has  OOMScoreAdjust](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd.exec.5.html).

You may disable the OOM killer entirely. However, in extreme memory pressure the system may not be able to respond, or panic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use supervisord to manage process.
Supervisor can set memory quota.